# Drill Bit Accessory Identification

Tags: tools, powertools, bits

I have a set of DeWalt drill bits, and there was one piece included that I don't know the use for.

Pictures (quarter for scale):
[image: Top with Philips head]

[image: "PULL" sticker that I never took off]
[image: All bits that came in the set, don't remember how it was packaged.]

<strike>The set includes a magnetic sleeve as well, but don't think it is related.</strike>
*Edit: Possibly related to magnetic sleeve. Was useful for helping push a bit out of there...*

**What is this drill bit accessory?**

Comment: @isherwood I don't recall exactly where it was in the packaging. The drill came with a tote bag, drill, battery, charger, drill bits in a folding box (1/16" -> 1/2"), and screwdriver bits in a folding box that included the mystery piece and magnetic sleeve.

Comment: Just a guess, but I suspect that it's a place holder. It would wedge into the appropriate bit slot, engaging a philips head bit on one end and the extension sleeve on the other. I don't see that working in the bit placement of the supplied photos, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several on line sources report it is for demonstration purposes. It is there to show you how  the magnetic holder works. Pull, Tire, Tirez, are translated as "PULL" in English. This may explain why there is no holder in the case for it.

Comment: It's definitely this. It probably came with the magnetic bit holder. The packaging for these comes with this piece.

Comment: Do you have any links where you saw this? Edit and add one to your answer, and I'll accept as the winner.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a “keeper” for the magnetic bit. In the old days putting the keeper on the magnet would retain the magnetic strength. Modern magnets are much less likely to need this, now have much lower “magnetic permeability”

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a very similar yellow (same brand) drill bit set, and this partial screw was accessible without opening the package. As other answers mention, it is for demonstrating the magnetic screw holder - and usable by potential customers shopping in the store, while the product is on the display shelf.

So, it is not really useful to keep, unless you happen to need a chunk of metal that shape and size for something else.